# Pyspark to get current timestamp with time zone

Tags: scala, pyspark

I am trying to get the current timestamp with time zone using current_timestamp method in pyspark.
But getting "**SQLException: Unsupported type TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE**"

```
val connection_properties = Map(
    "url" -> CONNECTION_URL, 
    "user" -> USER, 
    "password" -> PASSWORD, 
    "driver" -> DRIVER_CLASSNAME
)

val source_df=spark.read.format("jdbc").options(connection_properties)

val test=source_df.option("query","select current_timestamp as create_ts, AB.emp_id, AB.emp_name from EMPLOYEE AB" ).load()
```

[image]

But the value which I am expecting for create_ts is something like 2023-03-09 23:09:50.379 +0530.
Can anyone please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `current_timestamp` in query. Try to acheive it using DataFrame.

```
val test = source_df.option("query","select AB.emp_id, AB.emp_name from EMPLOYEE AB" ).load()
```

Add

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.current_timestamp

test.withColumn("create_ts", current_timestamp).show()
```